# How to give a size using realloc?

Tags: c, realloc

I want to give a random size to `pointer` and I want to add some elements to the `pointer`. I want to give place to the `pointer` enough size. For example, if I have `10` elements in `pointer`, I want to give place `40` `byte` to `pointer`. But when I looked to my code, initially I gave so much size for the element.
I want to see as an output:

67
11
64
7

67
11
64
7
23
81
88
35
12
5
7

The size of memory=40

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main() {
        
        int *k;
        int i=0,j=0,t=0;
        int array[20]={67,11,64,7};
        
        k=malloc(5*sizeof(int));
        k=array;
        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            printf("%d\n",k[i]);
        }
        
        k=realloc(k,50*sizeof(int));
        
        k[4]=23;
        k[5]=81;
        k[6]=88;
        k[7]=35;
        k[8]=12;
        k[9]=5;
        k[10]=7;
        for(j=0;k[j]!='\0';j++){
        
        printf("%d\n",k[j]);
        }
        
        k=realloc(k,(j+1)*sizeof(int));
        
        for(t=0;k[t]!='\0';t++){
            
            printf("%d\n",k[t]);
        }
        
        printf("the size of the memory=%d \n",j*4);
        printf("the size of the memory=%d \n",t*4);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You can't resize an automatic variable like `array` which is what you are trying to do since you do `k=array;` (and leak the memory previously allocated).

Comment: `k=array` is an assignment that makes the `malloc`'d memory lost. You cannot copy an array in this manner.

Comment: Just delete the `k=array;` line and it should work.

Comment: @CareyGregory The code that follows assumes k contains the  4 elements in `array`. Without a loop (or memcpy) to copy those elements, the code will *not* produce what the OP wants.

Comment: I don't understand the closing. I thought the question was clear, has a MRE and doesn't need additional details.

Comment: @JeffHolt Yeah, you're right. Just goes to show you how much time I spend on questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't resize an automatic variable like `array` which is what you are trying to do since you do `k=array;` (and leak the memory previously allocated).

You can copy the data from `array` into the allocated memory pointed out by `k` instead:

```
int array[20] = {67, 11, 64, 7};
int *k = malloc(sizeof array);
memcpy(k, array, sizeof array);
```

The loop condition you use is a tad confusing though:

```
for (j = 0; k[j] != '\0'; j++)
```

I suggest comparing with `0` instead.

The *"the size of the memory"* that you print out at the end is however not accurate. The size of the allocated memory at the end is `(j+1)*sizeof(int)`, that is, `12 * sizeof(int)`, since `k[11]` is the first element being `0`.

A word of caution is also in place: Your program currently has defined behavior because the array does contain `0`:s in the positions `[11, 19]`. Just be aware that the extra memory allocated by `realloc` contains indeterminate values, so had your original array been only 11 elements big, you had read those indeterminate values when you compare with `\0` (or preferably `0`) and you would never know what the result would be. It could continue searching for `\0` out of bounds.

Note: Don't forget to `free(k);` when you're done with it.